# Google script that opens and Excel file on my computer (from G-Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I'm looking for a script that I can run from Google Spreadsheet that will open a specific Excel file that is located on my computer.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not totally sure what you mean with running from Google Spreadsheet, if you want to execute a script by clicking a button in a specific Google Spreadsheet for example, that’s possible. See Google’s documentation: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus.

As far as I know access local files is impossible, since GAS is a [cloud](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) based service so it won’t be able to connect to your personal computer. My solution would be to add the specific Excel file(s) to your Google Drive. When those file(s) are located in your Google Drive folder any Google App Script can access them.

EDIT

You can open a Excel file with Google Spreadsheet(only if the file is located in your drive). With a right-mouse-click you can choose open with > Google Spreadsheets, this creates an duplicate of your Excel file as Google Spreadsheet. If opened copy the URL, if written a simple script you can start with, which works fine for me:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for(var i =  0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    var range  = sheets[i].getRange(1, 1, sheets[i].getLastRow(), sheets[i].getLastColumn());
    var values = range.getValues();
    for(var j = 0; j < sheets[i].getLastRow(); j++){
      Logger.log(values[j][0].toString());
    }
  }  
}
```

This code loops through all sheets in your Spreadsheet(outer for-loop) and get the range of each sheet, it convert this range to values and logs every value in the first column from every row(inner for-loop).

You can attach this script to a button in a Spreadsheet as explained in the Google documentation. Hope this will answer your question, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer wolteeer!

I can definitely put the Excel file in Google Drive if it will allow me to open it by clicking a button from a Google Spreadsheet!
My level of coding is pretty basic to be honest, any chance you can help me with that?
Thanks!!

Comment: If you use Google Sync and put that Excel file inside of your local google drive then You might possibly be able to accomplish that.  I don't know how to access Excel spreadsheets.  Check addons.

Comment: @AviG see my edit I hope this is what you've been looking for

Comment: @wolteeer I did exactly what you wrote - opened the XL file in G-Spreadsheet, put the script with the GS url and ran it, but basically nothing happened and the Excel file didn't open.
Anything I might have missed?

Comment: Try this function and , if you actually want to open(graphically) a sheet sorry my mistake, I thought you wanted to open it in script environment: 

function myFunction() {
  var ssName = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url").getName();
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(ssName).activate();
}

Comment: Thanks again for the answer @wolteeer - unfortunately it still doesn't do anything when I run that script :(   
Is there anything I need to activate/set maybe?

Comment: @wolteeer hey, I'm not sure why it's not working but I'll try to clarify the solution I was looking for:
1. I wanted to have a button/script in my Google Spreadsheet that will open for me an Excel file but in the Excel format and not Google Spreadsheet. The reason is because the Google Sheet is connected to the Excel file, so it will open that Excel file automatically so I can refresh the data (import from Google Sheets) and play with it (e.g. graphs for presentations). That link will "save" me the action of actually looking and opening the Excel file myself every time.